# MS Access - SQL Query for Max Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am creating a schedule calendar which has been working great, but I want to adjust the SQL so that it only shows when the next job has to be done. I was thinking the best way to achieve this would be via the MAX() function, however when i run the code Access doesn't seem to like it.

```vb
Public Sub LoadArray()
'This sub loads an array with the relevant variables from a query
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rsFiltered As Recordset
Dim strQuery As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Text23 As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Text23 = Forms.frmPreventativeMenu.Form.CompanyName.Value

strQuery = "SELECT tblWMYReports.Company, tblWMYReports.Machine, MAX(tblWMYReports.NextDate), tblWMYReports.WMY " _
        & "FROM tblWMYReports " _
        & "WHERE (((tblWMYReports.Company)= " & Text23 & " ));"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strQuery)
With rs

    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    'Ensures the recordset contains records

        For i = 0 To UBound(MyArray)
        'Will loop through the array and use dates to filter down the query
        'It firsts checks that the second column has true for its visible property
            If MyArray(i, 1) = True Then
                .Filter = "[NextDate]=" & MyArray(i, 0)
                'To filter you must open a secondary recordset and
                'Use that as the basis for a query
                'This makes sense as you are building a query on a query
                Set rsFiltered = .OpenRecordset
                If Not rsFiltered.BOF And Not rsFiltered.EOF Then
                    'If the recordset is not empty then you are able
                    'to extract the text from the values provided
                    Do While Not rsFiltered.EOF = True

                        MyArray(i, 2) = MyArray(i, 2) & vbNewLine & DLookup("MachineName", "tblMachine", "MachineID=" & rsFiltered!Machine)
                        MyArray(i, 2) = MyArray(i, 2) & " - " & DLookup("WMY", "tblWMY", "ID=" & rsFiltered!WMY)

                    rsFiltered.MoveNext
                    Loop
                End If
            End If

        Next i

End If
    .Close
End With

ExitSub:
    Set db = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "There has been an error. Please reload the form.", , "Error"
    Resume ExitSub

End Sub
```

Comment: *Access doesn't seem to like it.* - that's not very helpful. The error message would be. Also see: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Thank you for the link, have taken a read and it is extremely useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to aggregate one column with an aggregate function like `Sum()`, `Max()`, `Count()` or similar, then every other column that isn't being aggregated must show up in the SQL's GROUP BY clause:

```
strQuery = "SELECT tblWMYReports.Company, tblWMYReports.Machine, MAX(tblWMYReports.NextDate), tblWMYReports.WMY " _
        & "FROM tblWMYReports " _
        & "WHERE (((tblWMYReports.Company)= " & Text23 & " )) " _
        & "GROUP BY tblWMYReports.Company, tblWMYReports.Machine, tblWMYReports.WMY;"
```

I can't guarantee that is going to do what you want it to, since I'm not familiar with your data, code, or application, but it should get you through the error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was my initial concern but adding the group by still results in the same error.

Comment: Perhaps you need an alias on that field. It would help if you shared the error and the line on which it occurs. My guess is that `MAX(tblWMYReports.NextDate) as tblWMY` may help.

Comment: I could kiss you right now >.< it's working perfectly now! I needed both the alias and "GROUP BY" clause. Thank you so much again.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that did the trick! I'll take a raincheck on the kiss though.

Answer (score 1):

You must use a properly formatted string expression for the date value:

```
.Filter = "[NextDate] = #" & Format(MyArray(i, 0), "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
```